# Use of NSRunloop for avoiding event driven code

Tags: ios

I am using NSUrlConnection for making http requests. I want to avoid event driven code, so I am making use of NSRunloop in the following way:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]
                         initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:_urlString]
                         cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                         timeoutInterval: 10
                         ];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]  initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(!connection) 
{
    DebugLog(@"Creating a connection has failed");
    [self setValidationRequestResult:false];
} 
else 
{
    NSRunLoop* currentRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [self.connection start];
    while (self.isConnectionComplete == NO) 
    {
        NSDate* dateLimit = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.05];
        [currentRunLoop runUntilDate:dateLimit];
    }

    //TODO: check release of NSUrlConnection
   }
}

// Now perform remaining tasks ........
```

Is it okay to NSRunLoop in way shown above or should we post notifications in "didFailWithError" and "connectionDidFinishLoading" to write logic after the http request is done?

Comment: What is your reasoning behind "avoiding" event driven code? NSURLConnection was designed to attach itself to a runloop and post callbacks when data is available.

Comment: I want to perform certain tasks after obtaining response from the http request. If I write event driven code, I have to use PostNotification after the NSUrlConnection task is done and this forces me to break the code that can be hard to understand.

Comment: Better question, why aren't you just using `+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]`?

Comment: Blocking any thread is a bad idea (which is what sendSynchronousRequest does). Making the operating system do so many context switches (assuming you put the request on a separate thread), especially on a single core device, is bad on many levels (battery life, overall application performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that approach may be technically correct, I would encourage you to ask why you want to do this.

NSURLConnection was designed to attach itself to a runloop so the runloop can continue and not tie up that thread.

What I've done in my applications is have a class dedicated to managing my networking code and have delegate callbacks or pass in blocks to handle completion. You mentioned using Notifications and that is also a good idea.

This is the nature of asynchronous networking code. It makes the code a bit more complicated, but your application will be better off.